# Un terme français pour rendre l'anglais « chipmunking » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire

Comment pourrait-on traduire en français l'anglais *chipmunking*, mot d'emploi relativement récent qui n'a pas encore fait son entrée dans les dictionnaires conventionnels<sup>1</sup> et qui décrit le fait d'entasser le maximum possible de nourriture dans sa bouche<sup>2</sup> lors d'un concours de nourriture ?

Je me demande si on pourrait trouver quelque chose de plus imagé que « se remplir la bouche de nourriture », « entasser trop longtemps la nourriture dans sa bouche » qui décrivent l'action mais ne rendent pas l'image de l'animal [les joues gonflées de nourriture](https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/eastern-chipmunk-tamias-striatus-standing-600w-1092967241.jpg).
Je n'ai rien trouvé dans les rares articles en français consacrés à ce genre de concours<sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Le sens auquel je fais référence ici n'est aucun de ceux qui figurent dans l'*Urban Dictionary*.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> [Un site spécialisé](https://www.foodchallenges.com/eating-contest-tips/speed-eating-how-to-eat-food-faster/) :
*The act of “chipmunking” in the competitive eating world refers to filling your mouth so completely full with food that your cheeks bulge out and make you look like a chipmunk (hence the term)*.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_eating#Rules_and_overview_of_events): *Many eaters will attempt to put as much food in their mouths as possible during the final seconds of a contest, a practice known by professionals as "chipmunking"*.</sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup> Parmi lesquels : [Le Temps.ch](https://www.letemps.ch/societe/mangeurs-competition), [Slate.fr](http://www.slate.fr/story/172704/concours-mangeurs-mangeuses-gloutonnerie-hots-dogs-bagels), [Wikihow.](https://fr.wikihow.com/gagner-%C3%A0-un-concours-du-plus-gros-mangeur)</sup>

Comment: Très amusant. À mon avis on pourra choisir une traduction même si le sens n'en est pas clair au premier coup, si au moins il est fort probable qu'on arrive à en déduire le sens et à le visualiser -- tel est le cas en anglais.

Comment: En tout cas on a le substantif [abajoues](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abajoue) qui désigne les joues où les chipmunks et autres stockent la nourriture en attente d'être grignotée.

Comment: Je pense qu'en France l'animal à bajoues canonique est le hamster. On devrait donc décliner soit bajoue, soit hamster, soit une combinaison habile des deux...

Comment: Il y a bien le traditionnel _se gaver_, mais ça ne rend pas l'effet "joues de trompettiste".

Comment: @mcadorel … qui désignent les poches où les écureuil rayés et autres mammifères stockent …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Technique](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/technique)/[stratégie](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/strat%C3%A9gie) de l'[abajoue](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/abajoue) (ou de la [*bajoue*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bajoue)) en/de fin de
> concours de nourriture. [Les noms bajoue/abajoue ont été évoqués/suggérés en commentaire [1](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/47198/un-terme-fran%C3%A7ais-pour-rendre-langlais-chipmunking#comment95858_47198), [2]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/47198/un-terme-fran%C3%A7ais-pour-rendre-langlais-chipmunking#comment95865_47198)

On aime bien les [mots](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/47209/26366) suffixés en [*-age*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-age), mais comme le sens dépend du type de concours en question, *technique* ou *stratégie* sert fort bien à mon avis pour représenter un moyen d'atteindre un objectif. Incidemment ça ne me semble pas incompatible avec la fonction du suffixe [*-ing*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ing) dans le mot en anglais, que ce soit représenter l'action de ou avoir la qualité d'une chose.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Le remplissage des joues
- Le bourrage des joues
- Le "bajoutage" (avec une explication en annexe)